# Pygame Latency Issue using clock

Tags: python, pygame, clock

I made a snake game with pygame and it works fine. However, it's sometimes not very responsive to user inputs. I'm using a clock and delay to set how fast the snake should move.

Movement code:

```
pygame.time.delay(1)
clock.tick(7)
player.move()
render_screen()
```

Render Screen:

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
draw_grid()
player.draw()
food.draw()
screen.fill((0, 0, 0), (0, 513, 512, 50))
start.draw()
screen.blit(comic_font.render('Score: ' + str(score), False, (255, 100, 0)), (10, size + 5))
pygame.display.update()
```

Full Code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()


class Snake:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed_x = 1
        self.speed_y = 0
        segments = []
        for a in range(1, 4):
            segments.append(Segment(self.x - a, self.y))
        self.segments = segments

    def move(self):
        global score, game_mode
        # handle key inputs
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for key in keys:
            if self.speed_x == 0:
                if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    self.speed_x = -1
                    self.speed_y = 0
                if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    self.speed_x = 1
                    self.speed_y = 0
            elif self.speed_y == 0:
                if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    self.speed_x = 0
                    self.speed_y = -1
                if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    self.speed_x = 0
                    self.speed_y = 1

        # check for wall collisions
        if self.x + self.speed_x < 0 or self.x + self.speed_x > rows - 1 or self.y + self.speed_y > rows - 1 or \
                self.y + self.speed_y < 0:
            game_mode = "end"
            start.text = "RETRY"
            return None

        # moves snake
        self.segments.insert(0, Segment(self.x, self.y))
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += self.speed_y

        # checks for self collisions
        for segment in self.segments:
            if self.x == segment.x and self.y == segment.y and self.segments.index(segment)!=len(self.segments)-1:
                game_mode = "end"
                start.text = "RETRY"
                break

        # checks for eating food
        if self.x == food.x and self.y == food.y:
            food.x = random.randrange(0, 16)
            food.y = random.randrange(0, 16)
            score += 1
        else:
            self.segments.pop()

    def draw(self):
        for segment in self.segments:
            segment.draw()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.x * size / rows, self.y * size / rows, size / rows, size / rows))


class Segment:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255 - player.segments.index(self), 0),
                         (self.x * size / rows, self.y * size / rows, size / rows, size / rows))


class Food:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.x * size / rows, self.y * size / rows, size / rows, size / rows))


class button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, r, g, b, text, font, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.b = b
        self.g = g
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (self.r, self.g, self.b), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        screen.blit(self.font.render(self.text, False, (0, 100, 0)), (self.x + 10, self.y))

    def mouse_over(self, pos):
        if self.x < pos[0] < self.x + self.width and self.y < pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
            return True


def draw_grid():
    margin = size / rows
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for line in range(rows):
        x = x + margin
        y = y + margin

        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x, 0), (x, size))
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, y), (size, y))


def render_screen():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    draw_grid()
    player.draw()
    food.draw()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0), (0, 513, 512, 50))
    start.draw()
    screen.blit(comic_font.render('Score: ' + str(score), False, (255, 100, 0)), (10, size + 5))
    pygame.display.update()


size = 512
rows = 16

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size, size + 50))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

comic_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
game_mode = "wait"

player = Snake(8, 8)
food = Food(random.randrange(0, 16), random.randrange(0, 16))
start = button(size - 155, size + 5, 0, 255, 0, "PLAY", comic_font, 150, 40)

score = 0

render_screen()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if start.mouse_over(pos):
                if game_mode == "wait":
                    game_mode = "play"
                    start.text = "PAUSE"
                elif game_mode == "play":
                    game_mode = "wait"
                    start.text = "RESUME"
                elif game_mode == "end":
                    game_mode = "play"
                    start.text = "PAUSE"
                    score = 0
                    running = True
                    game_mode = "wait"
                    player = Snake(8, 8)
                    food = Food(random.randrange(0, 16), random.randrange(0, 16))
                render_screen()
    if game_mode == "play":
        pygame.time.delay(1)
        clock.tick(7)
        player.move()
        render_screen()
```

The full code is above to reproduce the problem.

After experimenting with this a bit, it seems that when the pygame.time.delay(1) is smaller, there will be less delay.

I think that the user gets the input read only between the tics so they have to input exactly on the spot.

I think maybe this is why the input is less behind when the delay is smaller as the delay will affect how long between each input.

Does anyone know why the game doesn't receive inputs well at certain times?

Comment: Why do you invoke `pygame.time.delay(1)` and `clock.tick(7)`? Most likely the issue is not related to the clock. How many event loops do you have?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  There is virtually no way we can diagnose a problem we can't reproduce, especially in an interdependent program such as this.

Comment: @Prune I gave the full code if you would like to reproduce it for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list, with the states of all keyboard buttons. It makes no sense to iterate through this list, because you just want to evaluate the current state of the keys <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Set the speed dependent on the pressed keys:

```py
class Snake:
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        # [...]
        
        # handle key inputs
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.speed_x == 0:
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.speed_x, self.speed_y = -1, 0
            elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
                self.speed_x, self.speed_y = 1, 0
        elif self.speed_y == 0:
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.speed_x, self.speed_y = 0, -1
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.speed_x, self.speed_y = 0, 1

        # [...]
```

---

[`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) delays to keep the game running slower than the given ticks per second. The states are returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) are evaluated, when the events are handled ([`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)).
Delay the game, after the events have been handled, the snake has been moved and the display was updated:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

    if game_mode == "play":
        player.move()
        render_screen()
        clock.tick(7) # <---
```

Comment: What happens to the delay statement? Also what is the difference between ticking the clock and delay? They seem to be doing the same thing

Comment: @JamesHuang [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) pause for a amount of time but [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) delayscompute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call and delays as long as necessary to limit to the specified frames per second. Do either `delay` or `tick`, but do not both, that doesn't make any sense.